# Remote password when online, and Local password when offline

Tags: security, passwords

So I have an app I'd like the user to be able to use when offline.  So there will be a password when online, and I'd to use the same password when user is offline.

It's not a super privacy sensitive app, but I'd still rather not store the entire hashed salted password locally on disk.  So I'm thinking, I'll just hash the password and store on disk the first 4 digits of the resulting hash or something.  That way, the user is still entering the same password online or offline.

Is this a good idea or am I horribly misguided?

Comment: Which hashing algorithm you've planned to use?

Comment: @Mahdi It doesn't matter what hash function you use if its only 4 digits...

Answer (score 1):

In general this feature is a bad idea.  An attacker doesn't even need SQL Injection to compromise a password hash.

If you store the first 4 digits of the resulting hash,  then you create the possibility of a large number of possible passwords.  4 digits of base 16 is 16^4 or only 65536 passwords,  or put another way it would always take no more than 65536 guesses to obtain some correct password...  which is **horribly insecure**.

Encrypted file systems have a similar problem.  They have to be able to verify a password,  and they want to prevent offline brute force.   They usually employ key stretching,  using bcrypt,  scrypt or even pbkdf2 to expend a fair amount ram and CPU in order to verify that the password is correct.  bcrypt with a few thousand rounds should be sufficient to prevent most offline attacks.

Comment: right, i was thinking of 4 digits basically just as a PIN code.  i could take the first 8 digits, or 12 digits, basically i just want to make sure whatever i store locally cannot be used to retrieve something that can be used to compromise the password on the server.

Comment: so i guess my question is really: aside from using say bcrypt, would the above actually be a great idea because even if it's locally compromised the password stored on the server is still safe?

Comment: @Victor its a bad idea in general,  there is no truly secure way of implementing this.

Comment: @Victor - The question is, how important is offline access for you? It _will_ make it easier to brute force the password, though only if you find the real password (not a collision), you have access to the server account as well. Maybe even more important, the account of other users is not endangered. On local side you could/should choose a much higher cost factor, then only weak passwords are realistically crackable. You wrote that you don't store really sensitive data, so i think this will work well for you.

Comment: @martinstoeckli There is absolutely no question hat its a venerability.  The real question is,  how much do you are about security?

Comment: @Rook - I cannot deny that it is a vulnerability, but it is the best you can do to authenticate an offline system. With the same argument you can say, that a windows login can never be safe. Indeed you are right, nevertheless the login is necessary and suffice for a lot of applications. And yes, the question is, how much security is necessary for the OP's application.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong when you store a hash of the password locally, just make sure you need a slow key derivation function like BCrypt to create the hash.

It is not necessary to transfer the hash-value over the internet, a possible process could look like that:

1. The user enters his password the first time.
2. We hash the password locally with a unique salt and a high cost factor, and store it locally.
3. We transfer the **original password** to the server.
4. The server hashes the password with another unique salt and a normal cost factor, and stores it in the database.

This way the local password-hash would look different as the server password-hash, you don't disclose anything about the server password-hash. Brute-forcing the local password will need more time because of the higher cost factor. Since you want to store something locally anyway, it's better to store a secure hash, instead of an unsafe part of a hash.

Comment: -1 this is a problem.  If the password hash is cracked then an attacker will have access to the account.  The hash transmitted to the server is now the password.

Comment: @Rook - You probably misunderstood an important point. It is not the idea to hash the password locally, send the hash to the server and hash it again. Instead the password will be hashed locally (to store a local hash), and then we send the _original password_ to the server and hash the password there again. This is the "normal" procedure, the only difference is, that we locally store an independend hash.

Comment: @Rook - I edited the answer and emphasized the part about the password to prevent misunderstandings. I'm sure you agree, that no hash is transmitted to the server and therefore cannot act as the password.